# Как обновлять поля в таблице?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Всем доброго времени суток!

Возникла такая проблема.
Есть таблица с номерами телефонов:

```
Telephone

client_id
company_id
number
```

Т.е. в данной таблице хранятся телефоны клиентов и компаний. У клиентов и компаний может быть по несколько телефонов. При вставке и выборке все просто и понятно.

Но проблема вот в чем: как обновить поля?

Пробовал через `UPDATE telephone SET number='".$_POST[number][$i]."' WHERE company_id='".$_SESSION['company_id']."'` ,

Но, как и логично, он заполнял для данной компании все телефоны вначале одним номер`($_POST[number][1])`, потом вторым `($_POST[number][2])`, и ...

В итоге получается, что в записях таблицы `Telephone` в поле `number` где `id_company='".$_SESSION['company_id']."'` сохраняются значения только последнего `$_POST[number][]`.

И еще раз: как обновить поля? Обновлять значения, для простоты, можно по порядку.

Comment: А что вам мешает передать в запрос client_id и company_id ? Тогда вы однозначно определите что обновлять.

Comment: у меня может быть и company_id=1 и client_id=1

Comment: ну надо поределиться что является ключом к вашей записи я надеюсь такого не может быть несколько полностью идентичных записей ?

Comment: В данном ответе просто продублирован вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Если таблица только с 3мя полями то тут сложненько.

Добавь поле id

```
id
client_id
company_id
number
```

Обновлять теперь просто.

Допустим у одной компании 4-10 номеров, да не важно.

Есть поле `type="text"`, где ты выводишь 1 номер как я полагаю.
Рядом поставь еще одно поле `type="hidden"` с `value="id{записи}"` и `name="id_record"`

Ну и обновлять будешь просто по id

```
UPDATE telephone SET number='".$_POST[number][$i]."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id_record']."'
```

Ну и все, обычно и обновляют по id, это поле автоинкремент, не повторяется.

Comment: Поддерживаю! Нужен ещё один реквизит как минимум (id), чтобы можно было идентифицировать все имеющиеся телефоны у компании. И обновлять нужно не махом, а конкретные экземпляры, на которые ссылаться как раз по id.